# Getting some just posted data

Tags: jquery

I am using this code to post some data

```
$('.update_btn').live("click",function() 
{
var ID = $(this).attr("id");
var dataString = 'msg_id='+ ID;

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
 url: "get-data.php",
 data: dataString,
 cache: false,
 success: function(){
 //alert(dataString);//is not empty
 getData();
 }
});
return false;
});

function getData()
{
   $.ajax({ 
      type: "GET",    
      url: 'get-data.php',                                                                   
      success: function()          
      {
      var jq = '<?php echo $_POST['msg_id'];?>';   
      alert(jq);      
      } 
    });
}
```

and function data to retrieve the just posted data but the `var jq` has no post data.What could be the cause?.

Comment: PHP is serverside. Javascript is client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being that you're using jQuery (or any JavaScript) you don't embed PHP code into it...

Assuming that you're only wanting to return the `msg_id` and nothing else your `get-data.php` would be something like this:

```
<?php
  // all the database work here to obtain the id..

  echo $data['msg_id'];
?>
```

Which would then turn your getData function to this:

```
function getData()
{
   $.ajax({ 
      type: "GET",    
      url: 'get-data.php',                                                                   
      success: function(jq)          
      {
      alert(jq);      
      } 
    });
}
```

Now, to expand on this -- if your return is going to be some sort of an array you'll want to use json_encode in your php...  like so:

```
<?php
$data = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table"), MYSQL_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Which logically, because we're returning a `json array` our JavaScript also changes:

```
function getData()
{
   $.ajax({ 
      type: "GET",    
      url: 'get-data.php',                                                                   
      success: function(response)          
      {
      var jq = $.parseJSON(response);
      alert(jq.msg_id);      
      } 
    });
}
```

Not much of a difference between the two..  But hopefully this answer has put you further on the path to an enlightened understanding of the tools you are attempting to use..  There are plenty of jQuery tutorials out there if you only google for them...  Many JavaScript die hards (myself included), will urge you to learn Native JavaScript so that you can understand what is happening behind the scenes of jQuery.  It is a very good idea to do, and again there is a lot of information and tutorials about it if you google for it.

I'm sure some people have some books they can recommend for your reading as well..

Comment: Not unaware, just lose my head when I go back to regular code not using my custom framework.  I did update it to something a little more plausible though..  Should be correct now.

Comment: The thing i started to learn jquery with a challenging example.I am hopeful i wrap my head around this thing before the night ends.

Comment: @flapjack , instead of "learning jquery" you should begin with learning proper javascript. Would you start learning GWT without knowing Java ?

Comment: I have a plan to study js like a pro.Its only today that i got some pretty book on js patterns but as of now,i want to make a basic crud app,nothing complicated though.

Answer (score 2):

`success: function(r) { alert(r); }`

You're trying to mix PHP and JS in a really weird way. Spit out the posted variable in your PHP AJAX handler script.

Comment: Please explain a little further.What do you mean spit out?.

Comment: You have to run that in the script that the AJAX function is calling.

Comment: Okay,thanks.I shall have to re arrange the example i am using.Its flagmented into various files.Thanks.